# Cannot inject dependency into ASP.NET Web API 2 Controller using Ninject 3.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, ninject

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 project, and I have been using Ninject 3.2 and Moq to test normal controllers for a while. It is pretty easy with the latest version, here is my code:

```
namespace CianaConsultancy.POC.Abstract
{
    public interface IAuditRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<User> Users { get; }
    }
} 


namespace CianaConsultancy.POC.Entities
{
    public class User
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
    }
}


namespace CianaConsultancy.Controllers
{
    public class POCController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IAuditRepository repository;
        public POCController(IAuditRepository auditRepo)
        {
            this.repository = auditRepo;
        }

        public string Index()
        {
            var user = (from u in repository.Users
                     select u).FirstOrDefault();
            return user.UserId;
        }
    }
}
```

In NinjectWebCommon.cs:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    Mock<IAuditRepository> mock = new Mock<IAuditRepository>();

    mock.Setup(m => m.Users).Returns(
        new List<User>
        {
            new User {
                UserId = "185b36c3"
            }
        }
    );
    kernel.Bind<IAuditRepository>().ToConstant(mock.Object);
}
```

It works fine.

Now I am moving to Web API controllers, and as I did not find any useful blogs on this topic, I just did it the same way as normal controller:

```
namespace CianaConsultancy.Controllers
{
    public class DynmQuestionGroupController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly IAuditRepository repository;

        public DynmQuestionGroupController()
        {

        }
        public DynmQuestionGroupController(IAuditRepository auditRepo)
        {
            this.repository = auditRepo;
        }
        public IEnumerable<User> Get()
        {
            return repository.Users;
        }
    }
}
```

It does not work, the repository property is null in Get() method.

What do I miss? Thanks.

Comment: Probably because you're providing a default (empty) constructor as well. Also, did you wire WebApi dependency resolver to Ninject?

Comment: If I dont put it there, it will give an error about it. saying it needs a parameterless constructor. I had no choice, you see.

Comment: That's the whole point. Ninject is supposed to provide that dependency for you. See http://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2016/04/web-api-2-and-ninject-how-to-make-them-work-together/. In essence, you need this: `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);`

Comment: You are right, thank you, unfortunately, I cannot mark yr words as correct solution, coz it's comment. BTW, I need to install Ninject.Web.WebAPI package as well, and it is not mentioned in that blog.